# Where on my Mac is Xcode 4.5 Installed?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I downloaded and installed Xcode 4.5 Beta earlier this morning, opened it briefly and then quit it. No specific reason I quit it, I just wanted to make sure it would open and open a current project, which it did.

I've since needed to open it again, but I cannot find it ANYWHERE on my Mac. I tried spotlight search, looking in HD/Developer/, HD/Apps, but cannot see it anywhere. Not downloaded a beta of Xcode before so don't know if it's sat in some super secret location? Haha.

I'm on OS X 10.7.4 if that helps.

Many thanks,

Nathan

Comment: Right click on `Xcode` icon in Dock, select `Options`, then `Show in Finder`.

Comment: Did you look in your Applications folder?

Comment: I've got Xcode in my dock, but this is 4.4.1 (public release). When I opened 4.5 (beta) that also appeared in my dock next to my current version, with a slightly different icon (red banner thing in the top left it). I've checked and it isn't in my Applications folder.

Comment: Yup, tried that too and only shows my public release version. Starting to think it has just disappeared somewhere...

Comment: If you just downloaded Xcode it might be in the downloads folder, otherwise try spotlight search on the entire HD, name is Xcode45-DP4 (for the 4th developer preview)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but seems I may have just removed it somehow, so I'm going to try download and reinstall. Not sure why the question has deserved a -1 though, who ever did that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the icon of an application in the Dock and select `Options` -> `Show in Finder` to look up the path of an executable.

To be specific about Xcode 4.5 Beta: It is installed with the custom name `Xcode45-DP4.app` in your Applications folder. The custom name prevents overriding the current release version Xcode 4.4.

*EDIT: If you can't find the Xcode 4.5 anymore maybe you have just launched the app directly from the DMG and now have unmounted it?*

Comment: I think what I've done then is what's in your edit. I did unmount and then delete the DMG file. I've since started to redownload it as I'd deleted it from my trash

Comment: Yup, that is what I had done. I think usually you get the option to drag it into your apps folder, but without it being there I must have just assumed it was installed somewhere. Opened the DMG and then dragged the app into the apps folder myself. Silly, but no worries. Thanks